# Execute a string in Python inside a function so that the variables defined can be used

Tags: python, string, variables

Given a string (e.g. `"lista=[1,2,3]"`) I would like to be able to use the variable `lista`.

exec() does the work outside a function, but when used inside a function the variables cannot be used in that same function. I guess it has something to do with local and global variables but I don't really understand the problem.

For example,

```
def funcion(texto):
    exec(texto)
    print(lista)

funcion("lista = [3,4,5]")
```

Gives the error: `NameError: name 'lista' is not defined`.

Comment: More help on exec [here](https://blog.finxter.com/python-exec/). But, I would try to avoid using it entirely, if possible. It's risky to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: *Are you sure you really need `exec`?* What, exactly, are you actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Given a string (e.g. ´"lista=[1,2,3]"´) I would like to be able to use the variable ´lista´.

Answer (score 0):

add globals

```
def funcion(texto):
    exec(texto, globals())
    print(lista)

funcion("lista = [3,4,5]")
```

Comment: Using `globals` will overwrite a variable `lista` in the global scope. There might be a reason why this should be in a function.

Comment: Thank you both! And do by any chance know a way of solving the problem without adding that to the set of global variables?